# python version conflict with json.dumps

Tags: python, json, blockchain, pyenv

I am a newb to `python`. I am running a script I got on the web :

```
python file.py
```

I get this :

```
File "file.py", line 293
    print json.dumps(evaluate(), indent=4)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I read it is related to python version, that should be some `2.7`. So I downloaded `pyenv`. And I set the right version in the directory that contains `file.py` : `pyenv local 2.7.10`. But I still get the same error.

(For information, I am trying to install `blockchain` tool : ethereum)

Comment: Which operating sytem are you using? Does the first line of the python script have something like `#!/usr/bin/python` in it (the "shebang")? I don't use `pyenv` so can't say much about it. How about writing an experimental script that uses that same "shebang" (if present) and then just does `import sys;print(sys.version)` to make something easier to experiment with.

Comment: @tdelaney yes it is a python script with `#!/usr/bin/python` and indeed I found this : `3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0`. I don't know how to get rid of that - do you have any idea ?

Comment: Weird environment problems are hard to figure out! `/usr/bin/python` is usually python 2, which is what you want for the old style print statement (`print something` as opposed to `print(something)`). Python 3 usually shows up as `/usr/bin/python3`. What does `which python` say? I'm not familiar with `anacoda` either and it may have something else in the path.

Comment: @tdelaney `which python` outputs `/myhome/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: @tdelaney yes I was able to lake it work by changing the `PATH` that was set to some path related to `anaconda`

Comment: Running the script as `./file.py` may work also (it may need a `chmod u+x file.py`).

Answer (score 17):

Python 3.x changed print statement to be print functions

Python 2.x:

```
print "Hello World"
```

Python 3.x

```
print("Hello World")
```

So because you are running on python 3.x you will need to update your code to use the 3.x print style (e.g., print function calls).

```
print( json.dumps(evaluate(), indent=4) )
```

Comment: There are other differences between 2 and 3 besides just `print`. Converting may be a major lift.